# Single click in "Find Results" to open file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

In the "Find Results", I double click an item to open the file.

How can I open a file in this panel with single click?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only single click option I found for this opens it in a preview tab.  By default, I believe this setting is enabled (perhaps you turned it off at some point or you have the preview tab settings completely turned off?)

Under Tools → Options → Environment → Tabs and Windows there is a "Preview Tab" section.  Enable the "Preview selected files in Find Results" option:

[image: preview find results option]

This should make it so that when you click once on one of those file paths, it will open in a preview tab. From there, you can look over the file as if its any other tab.